# Get the value from cell as integer DATAGRIDVIEW C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to create a general method to update my database for all my classes.
I have a primary key, so when I want to update something I say "Do this, where id = @id"

My question is how can I get the value of primary key in my datagridview as an integer to pass as an argument to my update method. I need a int value because I know how to make with string. It must be an int value.

Comment: Are you asking about `int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()` ?

Comment: lol i know int.Parse but I never thought about that to use that haha but yes it worked! haha

Comment: int cell = int.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());

Comment: Glad to hear that. Posted as answer)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `int.Parse` to correctly parse string to integer.

But I would advice you to use `string.TryParse` if you are not sure about the contents of your cell:

```
int result = -1;
bool parsed = int.TryParse(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString(), out result);
```

And then in your code:

```
if(parsed) {
    // everything ok, use result here
} else {
    // something wrong with parsing
}
```